# How do I install byobu in ec2 ami

Tags: amazon-ec2, installation, package, yum, amazon-ami

I know it was possible usint a package manager since i did it once a time ago. But now if I try

> sudo yum install byobu

it just fails ...

> Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
>   Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security, update-motd
>   Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile 
>   * amzn-main: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
>   * amzn-updates: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
>   amzn-main
>   amzn-updates
>   Setting up Install Process
>   No package byobu available.
>   Error: Nothing to do

Answer (score 31):

Not sure why, but the EPEL repo is installed, but disabled by default.  You can enable it permanently by changing the setting `"enabled=1"` in the `[epel] stanza` of `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`

Or you can leave it disabled and still install byobu:

```
sudo yum install --enablerepo=epel byobu
```

You can have a look at what packages are available in the epel repo with:

```
sudo yum list --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=epel
```

Comment: As of 2019 - epel is not available in AZ Linux2.. You can enable it using this command `sudo yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm`

Comment: Official info on how to enable epel on AMI 2 [here](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-enable-epel/)

Answer (score 6):

**For Amazon Linux 2:**

> You would need to install the EPEL release package for EL7 based AMI and enable the EPEL repository.

**You may execute below:**  ⤵︎

```sh
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel      # Install epel from Amazon's Linux Extras

sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel      # Enable EPEL repo in case disabled

sudo yum install byobu -y                  # Install byobu

byobu -v                                   # Verify Version
```

Here is the alternative source just in case Linux Extras don't work for you.

```sh
# (optional) Install EPEL repository from Fedora
sudo yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

*Reference*: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-enable-epel/

---

**Tested On**

Name: Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-0323c3dd2da7fb37d (64-bit x86) / ami-0ce2e5b7d27317779 (64-bit Arm)

Answer (score 3):

The error message indicates that the package `byobu` is not available in the amzn-main repository.

You can manually install it from another repository

```
cd ~
wget ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/epel/5/x86_64/byobu-3.4-2.el5.noarch.rpm    
sudo yum install byobu-3.4-2.el5.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: The file has been updated: `ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/epel/5/x86_64/byobu-5.73-4.el5.noarch.rpm`. But I advise to check on `ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/epel/5/x86_64/`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone needs a new link for
[byobu](ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/epel/7/x86_64/b/byobu-5.73-4.el7.noarch.rpm)

So you can install it by

```
wget ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/epel/7/x86_64/b/byobu-5.73-4.el7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install byobu-5.73-4.el7.noarch.rpm
```